# crawling imdb database using python and lxml

Tags: python, web-crawler, lxml

hxs = lxml.html.document_fromstring(requests.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/" + id).content)

```
movie = {}

try:
    movie['title'] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="overview-top"]/h1/span[1/text()'[0].strip()


except IndexError:
    movie['title']
```

i am not able to understand the meaning of "hxs.xpath('//*[@id="overview-top"]/h1/span[1]/text()')[0].strip()"

Comment: that seems like just a way to select elements. you might want to look into something like PyQuery for a more friendly selector engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function **lxml.html.document_fromstring(string)** Parses a document from the given string. This always creates a correct HTML document, which means the parent node is , and there is a body and possibly a head.

```
hxs = lxml.html.document_fromstring(requests.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/" + id).content)
```

You can see the html using this code.

```
print lxml.html.tostring(hxs)
```

Considering the IMDb movie with title *tt1905041* , consider the html source code of the web page,

```
<td id="overview-top">
    <h1 class="header"> <span class="itemprop" itemprop="name">Fast &amp; Furious 6</span>
        <span class="nobr">(<a href="/year/2013/?ref_=tt_ov_inf" >2013</a>)</span>
    </h1>
</td>
```

hence as we need the title we parse it from the outer html,

**[@id="overview-top"]** would choose the desired id element

**h1**

**span[1](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath)** As there are multiple span elements we choose the 1st one.
similarly as we parse the html we get the following code,

```
movie['title'] = hxs.xpath('//*[@id="overview-top"]/h1/span[1]/text()')[0].strip()
print movie['title']
```

Output: Furious 6

More about XPath [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath)